# How to view data saved in Redis in html file?

Tags: html, node.js, redis

I want to print the data I saved in redis to the screen in the ana_sayfa_giris.html file, how can I do this?

When this command is run, res.redirect(`/ana_sayfa_giris`); with const data = wait connect.get(key); The data from here must also be forwarded to the home_page_login.html file.

```
app.post("/giris_sayfa", async (req, res) => {
  try {
   const { name, password } = req.body;

   const user = await collection.findOne({ name, password });
  
  
  if (!user || user.password !== password) {
      res.send("Kullanıcı bulunamadı veya şifre yanlış");
  } else {
    
    const user1 = await client.query('SELECT sehir, ulke, cepno, adres FROM postgres WHERE name = $1', [name]);
    console.log(user1.rows[0])
   
    const key = `kullanici-${name}`;
    const value = {
      name: name,
      sehir: user1.rows[0].sehir, 
      ulke: user1.rows[0].ulke,
      cepno: user1.rows[0].cepno,
      adres: user1.rows[0].adres,
    };
    await baglan.set(key, JSON.stringify(value));
     
    const data = await baglan.get(key);
    console.log(data)
    
    res.redirect(`/ana_sayfa_giris`);
  
  }
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send("Bir hata oluştu, lütfen tekrar deneyin.");
  }
});


 ana_sayfa_giris.html = 

      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <title>Ana sayfa giriş</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/ana_sayfa_giris.css">
       </head>
       <body>
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Ana sayfa</h1>
    <p>
        <strong>isim:</strong> <span class="name"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Şehir:</strong> <span class="sehir"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Ülke:</strong> <span class="ulke"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Cep telefonu:</strong> <span class="cepno"></span>
     </p>
      <p>
         <strong>Adres:</strong> <span class="adres"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```